# Why are coarse maps required to be proper?

Tags: coarse-geometry

In the context of [coarse spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarse_structure), a map between coarse spaces $f:X\to Y$ is called *coarse* if it is *bornologous* (it maps controlled sets to controlled sets), and *proper*, in the sense that preimages of bounded subsets are bounded. 
(A subset $B$ is bounded if $B\times B$ is controlled, or equivalently if $B\times\{x\}$ is for some point $x$.)

Why this last requirement? Why, for example, don't we want the constant map $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{Z}$ given by $x\mapsto 0$ to be a coarse map? What breaks down if we allow those?

Comment: It's a strange and unpractical convention, indeed. I encourage you not to include properness in the definition.

Comment: I agree with @YCor. I am currently writing* a text taking a categorical perspective on the subject in which I omit the proneness property from the definition.

Comment: * "writing" in my comment above should be taken in the weak sense: this project is kept being postponed due to other administrative duties and more urgent mathematical projects. I am not sure this process is converging for me :(

Comment: @UriBader I'd love to read that once it's ready. (In the meantime, is there any reference which does not use this convention?)

Comment: @geodude, none that I am aware of.